# How to remove the negative symbol for values in expression in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

```
FormatCurrency(
(SUM(iif(IsNothing(Fields!Planned.Value),0,Fields!Planned.Value))-(SUM(iif(IsNothing(Fields!Actuals.Value),
iif(IsNothing(Fields!Forecasts.Value),0,Fields!Forecasts.Value),
iif(Fields!Actuals.Value=0,iif(IsNothing(Fields!Forecasts.Value),
0,
Fields!Forecasts.Value),Fields!Actuals.Value))))),
iif(Parameters!DecimalDigits.Value=1,1,iif(Parameters!DecimalDigits.Value=2,2,0)),0,0,0)
)
```

this is my expression which is returning negative values and how to remove this negative sign in front of the number

Comment: Quite a complicated expression are you sure there isn't a problem? Or are the negatives showing you something important like an overrun in hours? If that's the case maybe you need to leave it or limit it to 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to turn the expression around. For instance, if

```
Planned - Actual
```

is giving you negative numbers and you want positive numbers then maybe you want

```
Actual - Planned
```

Otherwise you could just take the whole expression away from zero to reverse the sign:

```
0 - <expression>
```

Or if you really want to kill the negative sign regardless, then use `Absolute` - this returns the value as a positive number regardless

```
Abs(<expression>)
```

I would also remove the formatting part of the expression and put that into the `Format` property. Almost everything in SSRS can be an expression, so you don't have to do everything in the `Value` expression.